# iOS compile ffmpeg with modified source code

Tags: ios, ffmpeg

I modified udp.c and want to build libavformat.a for arm64,but it always failed with:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang is unable to create an executable file.
C compiler test failed.

Here is my compile.sh:

```
./configure \
--disable-ffmpeg \
--disable-ffplay \
--disable-ffprobe \
--disable-ffserver \
--enable-avresample \
--enable-cross-compile \
--target-os=darwin \
--arch=arm \
--cpu=cortex-a9 \
--cc="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang" \
--sysroot="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk" \
--extra-cflags="-arch arm64 -mfpu=neon -miphoneos-version-min=9.0" \
--extra-ldflags="-arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk -miphoneos-version-min=9.0" \
--enable-pic \
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone who came after me, do not try to run a script write by your self but to modify a script already been successful run.For this issue ,I modified `FFmpeg-iOS-build-script-master` and make change like this:

```
if [ ! -r $SOURCE ]
then
    echo 'FFmpeg source not found. Trying to download...'
    curl http://192.168.1.36/$SOURCE.tar.bz2 | tar xj \
        || exit 1
fi
```

And I put the tar.bz2 modified by my own to this server,then everything goes right :)